Is there a way to activate a destroyed/unpowered Mr Gutsy?
I was playing Fallout 4 and came across a destroyed (or simply shut down — not sure) Mr Gutsy. I noticed that if you long press E on the keyboard, you can carry him with you across the map.
Is there a way to bring him to a base and activate him if he's not destroyed, with another terminal?
Do terminals automatically "see" the robots that are nearby (the way all workbenches have access to each others' inventory when crafting)?

Is this a named gutsy, or one of the generic procedurally generated ones?

He was already named Mr gutsy

Short answer: No
With the Automatron DLC you could mimic a Gutsy of your own, but all robots are connected to specific terminals. Hauling him around has 0 value, best just to kill it for spare parts.

"Hauling him around has 0 value": what do you mean by that?

@Joachim the OP says he wants to carry it around using E. But that does nothing.. you just have a NPC with you that literally does nothing so why bother?

If you're playing on PC - and depending on whether the Mr Gutsy was previously alive (as opposed to one that spawns already dead) - you can open the console with `, click on the corpse, and type resurrect to revive it.
Note however, that most wild Mr Gutsy will be immediately hostile to the player (there are a couple of non-hostile random encounters though).
